# SpringBoot don't create datasource from yml config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, datasource

In `application.yml` I defined datasource:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver
    username: default
    url: jdbc:clickhouse://localhost:8123/default
```

I too create some config:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyConfig {

    @Getter
    private ReportRoutingDataSource dataSourceStorage = new ReportRoutingDataSource();

    @Bean("dataSourceStorage")
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        dataSourceStorage.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource);
        dataSourceStorage.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources());
        dataSourceStorage.afterPropertiesSet();
        return dataSourceStorage;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<Object, Object> resolvedDataSources() {
        //some another logic;
    }
}
```

ReportRoutingDataSource:

```
public class ReportRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return RequestContext.getKeyToChoseDataSource();
    }

}
```

I want use auto-configuration to create a default datasource from a yml file and add it to `dataSourceStorage.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource)` as default datasource.

I set annotation `@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)`, that my config is created after autoconfiguration of the standard datasource.

But, whent I start my app, I have error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceStorage' defined in class path resource [com/example/spring/MyConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=dataSource)}
```

But, why? How can I fix it?

Comment: You are defining a `DataSource` yourself and hence the auto config backs of. The `@AutoConfigureAfter` won't help  you here. Check the guide on manual configuring a datasource and how to bind properties to it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your 'dataSource' method with

```
@Bean("dataSourceStorage")
public ReportRoutingDataSource reportRoutingDataSource (@Autowired("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    ReportRoutingDataSource dataSourceStorage = new ReportRoutingDataSource();
    dataSourceStorage.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource);
    dataSourceStorage.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources());
    dataSourceStorage.afterPropertiesSet();
    return dataSourceStorage;
}
```

and get rid of the @Getter for ReportRoutingDataSource.